# what's wrong with the way I am splitting a string in python?

Tags: python, split

I looked in my book and in the documentation, and did this:

```
a = "hello"
b = a.split(sep= ' ')
print(b)
```

I get an error saying split() takes no keyword arguments. What is wrong?

I want to have ['h','e','l','l','o']
I tried not passing sep and just a.split(' '), and got ['hello']

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python allows a concept called "keyword arguments", where you tell it which parameter you're passing in the call to the function. However, the standard `split()` function does not take this kind of parameter.

To split a string into a list of characters, use `list()`:

```
>>> a = "hello"
>>> list(a)
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

---

As an aside, an example of keyword parameters might be:

```
def foo(bar, baz=0, quux=0):
    print "bar=", bar
    print "baz=", baz
    print "quux=", quux
```

You can call this function in a few different ways:

```
foo(1, 2, 3)
foo(1, baz=2, quux=3)
foo(1, quux=3, baz=2)
```

Notice how you can change the order of keyword parameters.

Comment: list() seems to work as well as a for loop. Whats more efficient?

Comment: @Jack S.: It depends on what you want to do, but a `for` loop might be the easiest if you just want to iterate through each character. Creating a list involves allocating memory for a list and copying each character, which a `for` loop wouldn't need to do.

Answer (score 5):

try just:

```
a = "hello"
b = a.split(' ')
print(b)
```

notice the difference: `a.split(' ')` instead of `a.split(sep=' ')`. Even though the documentation names the argument "sep", that's really just for documentation purposes. It doesn't actually accept keyword arguments.

In response to the OP's comment on this post:

`"a b c,d e".split(' ')` seperates "a b c,d e" into an array of strings. Each ' ' that is found is treated as a seperator. So the seperated strings are `["a", "b", "c,d", "e"]`. `"hello".split(' ')` splits "hello" everytime it see's a space, but there are no spaces in "hello"

If you want an array of letters, use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). `[letter for letter in string]`, eg `[letter for letter in "hello"]`, or just use the `list` constructor as in `list("hello")`.

Comment: I should have been more specific. I tried that and got ['hello'], I want ['h','e','l','l','o']

Answer (score 2):

Given a string `x`, the Pythonic way to split it into individual characters is:

```
for c in x:
    print c
```

If you absolutely needed a list then

```
redundant_list = list(x)
```

I call the list redundant for a string split into a list of characters is less concise and often reflects C influenced patterns of string handling.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
a = "hello"
b = list(a)
```